# Simple Combinations Binomial

Tags: combinatorics

There is a little sum I am stuck with.

Find the value of
$${1 \choose 0}+{4 \choose 1}+{7 \choose 2} +\ldots+{3n+1 \choose n}$$

where ${n \choose r}$ is the usual combination.

A little hint will be fine.

Comment: Are you looking for a closed form of the sum? Because [wolfram alpha's](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+from+k+%3D+0+to+n+of+%5B%283k%2B1%29+choose+k%5D) is kind of ugly...

Comment: Yes a general formula for integer n

Comment: I'd go with induction here.

Comment: Please write your steps

Answer (score -1):

Find the coefficient of $x^{0}$ in $\displaystyle  (1+x)+\frac{(1+x)^{4}}{x}+\frac{(1+x)^{7}}{x^{2}}+\ldots$
It's forming a geometric series.

Comment: Please write your calculations and give me final answer.